# Общее слово или два независимых ССП?

Tags: пунктуация

> Так необитаемая земля, в древних рощах которой «собирались демоны»,
>   будет расчищена и древний тракт подведёт к новым городским воротам
>   столицы.

Хочу запятую, но сумлеваюся...

Ога, щас запросют поширше контексту, а он - вот он он!

> ...После смерти Нерона местность эта будет включена в городской
>   померий. Император Аврелиан остановит вторжение германских племен на
>   севере Италии и, упреждая беды, повелит обновить стену Сервия, которая
>   была создана в IV веке до нашей эры. Более того, властелин заключит
>   сердце города во второе кольцо, протяженностью в 19 километров. Так
>   необитаемая земля, в древних рощах которой «собирались демоны», будет
>   расчищена и древний тракт подведёт к новым городским воротам столицы.
>
> ---

**P. S.** *Не правлю шапку вопроса, но конечно, это уже никакие не независимые ССП, а СПП + простое*.

Comment: Не сумлевайтесь. Ставьте.

Comment: @slava1947, придите, пожалуйста, на помощь!

Comment: Да трудно помочь-то. Не нравится мне это предложение. Я бы его вообще выкинул. Или полностью переработал. Не нравится "земля будет расчищена" -- от кого или от чего она будет расчищена? Не нравится "древний тракт подведёт" -- не хватает каких-то слов. Не нравится союз "и" -- заменил бы его на "а"... К сожалению, сейчас не могу много времени за компьютером проводить.

Comment: Спасибо, Слава. Автор увидит Ваши сомненья и размышленья.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Запятую лучше не ставить: **Так** необитаемая земля, в древних рощах которой «собирались демоны», будет расчищена и древний тракт подведёт к новым городским воротам столицы.

Общее слово (так, таким образом) относится к обоим предложениям, это **единое следствие** преобразований, его надо прочитать **без паузы**.

Comment: _Jasmin: это единое следствие преобразований, **его надо прочитать без паузы**._ === Без паузы? Хотел бы послушать, как это у Вас получится.

Comment: Без паузы, соответствующей сложному предложению, когда остановка голоса ПОДЧЕРКИВАЕТСЯ.  На этом месте будет произносительная пауза. Такие паузы присутствуют в простом  распространенном предложении.

Answer (score 1):

Я не могу понять, к чему это *так*. Работали внутри кольца и так расчистили  землю вне его и построили дорогу? Где логика? Я бы убрал это *так* и **так** утвердил право запятой на существование.

Comment: Ну как - к чему так? Шла подробная речь о необитаемости земли, и вдруг нам рассказали "как" всё изменилось.

Comment: Меняли в одном месте, а изменилось в другом. Странно при этом употреблять *как* и *так*.